# VBA code to convert a string format in to date format

Tags: vba, excel

I have a date format in excel which is

> Fri Aug 22 01:10:24 EDT 2014

I want to convert it into `08/22/2014 1:10 am` format using VBA coding.

Comment: What have you tried? It is important that you provide a minimal example of what you have tried, the inputs you gave it, the outputs you expected and the outputs you actually received.

Comment: Please clarify is "Fri Aug 22 01:10:24 EDT 2014" stored in a cell or in a variable? And in case of cell value - what is the data type: a string or a custom formatted date?

Comment: This is the first time I am using VBA. I tried The CDate function and trim function but to no success.

Comment: We use a portal and I downloaded the file as an excel sheet so this  is just as string format I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Function CONVDATE(mydate) As Date
    Dim arr
    arr = Split(mydate)
    CONVDATE = arr(1) & " " & arr(2) & " " & arr(5) & " " & arr(3)
End Function
```

This should work provided the expression is standard.
It will return a *Date* then you can then use the *Custom Format* in excel to get your desired format. HTH

**Result:**

[image]

You can use it as a Worksheet Function and enter as normal formula.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have a question on how do I assign a value of a coloumn and display in another coloumn. Also I need to do this for the entire coloumn. Thanks again :)

Comment: That's exactly the reason why I've written a function so you can use it in your worksheet like ordinary *Excel Function* then just copy paste formula.